# Amazon Marketplace FBA API connection issue - returns error 'Seller is not registered for basic fulfillment'

Tags: amazon-mws, fulfillment

We are trying to build a custom in house solution to MWS so that we can use Amazon FBA. We have professional accounts setup in both US and EU and we have triple checked that the accounts are registered for FBA. For some reason when we try the 'GetFulfillmentPreview' operation (or any other for that matter) we get the below error:

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/FulfillmentOutboundShipment/2010-10-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidRequestException</Code>
    <Message>Seller is not registered for Basic fulfillment.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>77690464-3c8f-4b5c-964e-3a89046fae7c</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

We have contacted Amazon who are looking into the issue, but were wondering if anyone here has had a similar issue? I would love to be made to look stupid with a simple solution but we have triple checked access codes, seller ID codes, registration tickboxes in our account, different APIs and operations etc, all with no joy.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For same parts of the API to work, you’ll have to provide tax information in your MWS Pro account. Otherwise you’ll get a

```
Seller is not registered for Basic fulfillment.
```

error message back.

Found in https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django-oscar-mws/latest/django-oscar-mws.pdf